# What is differences between supercharge and turbocharge?

Tags: transmission

My knowledge  about its  function is that both devices increase air pressure to fast engine combustion ? correct ? Answers  always appreciated   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple difference is that the turbocharger gets its power from the exhaust gas leaving the engine while the supercharger gets its power directly from the crankshaft.

This means the supercharger may need 20bhp to drive it but increases the engine output by 70bhp giving a net increase of 50bhp to the wheels. While the turbocharger does not take power directly from the engine (it uses the energy in the exhaust gas a change in enthalpy) and increases the engine power output.